# Reduction of the code. Reduce some for-loops into one python

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm working on a code in python. In particular the code is about scythe cipher encoding. I did it with some loops but I don't know if it's possible to reduce it in just one loop. Can you help me?
Here is my code:

```
for b in range(1, len(word), 6):
    word_list2.append(word[b])
print(word_list2) 

for c in range(2, len(word), 6):
    word_list3.append(word[c])
print(word_list3)

for d in range(3, len(word), 6):
    word_list4.append(word[d])
print(word_list4)

for e in range(4, len(word), 6):
    word_list5.append(word[e])
print(word_list5)

for f in range(5, len(word), 6):
    word_list6.append(word[f])
print(word_list6)
```

This code exactly does what I want but I want to know if it's possible to reduce everything in just one for loop.

HERE IS THE SOLUTION I DID LINKING THE ANSWER I RECEIVED AND WORKING ON IT:

```
word_list = []
for i in range(0,5):
    word_list1 = word[i::6]
word_lists = [word[start::6] for start in range(6)]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to use loops where slicing would do:

```
word_list1 = word[0::6]
word_list2 = word[1::6]
word_list3 = word[2::6]
word_list4 = word[3::6]
word_list5 = word[4::6]
word_list6 = word[5::6]
```

Each of these is now a new list object with every 6th element from `word`, starting at increasing first indices.

You'd not use separate variables however; you can easily make this a list with a list comprehension:

```
word_lists = [word[start::6] for start in range(6)]
```

Now you also have 6 lists, each with a selection of every 6th word, starting at indices 0 through to 5. You can address each list with `word_lists[0]`, `word_lists[1]`, etc.

Comment: You should update this to use append, your solution would overwrite existing word lists

Comment: @Parker: You can use *`list.extend()`* if they are not empty; `word_list1.extend(word[0::6])`. Or use `+=` augmented assignment. E.g. `word_list1 += word[0::6]`.

Comment: so I always have to create 6 different list, right?

Comment: @pp94: yes, this produces 6 different lists.

Comment: ok. Then I can link them into one list. But basically this was my request. should I have to create 6 different lists or can I use just one?

Comment: @pp94: These are 6 different lists inside one list. You had 6 different lists referenced by six different variable names, this is just the one variable name. I added a level of indirection.

Comment: aaaaaah ok. Now I read the update. So sorry @MartijnPieters I will try it

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters I reduce it more and I post my solution as edit of the question. Thanks for helping me

Comment: @pp94: your loop replaces the same variable over and over; it doesn't do much. You are also not using the variable defined in the first line.

Comment: I don't know @MartijnPieters but it works perfectly like your code

Comment: @pp94: sure, but that probably because you are not actually using `word_list` or `word_list1` in your code elsewhere.